# mobile web app structure of html files

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

I am new to mobile app development. I am have successfully created a single page app.I have to add more pages to it. Now I would like to know what is the correct way of doing it i.e I can add a different html file for every page as we do it in normal websites. Or I can put all the code in one html file, in different div blocks and then hide/show div as required.

I want to know :-

- Which is the correct/standard way of coding it ?
- What are the advantages of one over another?
- Any other suggestions.

It would be also very helpful if you could point me to some open source examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jquery mobile, I would suggest following approach (with all pages in a single html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <!-- meta, css and Scripts -->

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="login-page" class="login-page" data-theme="d">

    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="home-page" class="home-page" data-theme="d">

    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This will reduce some time in page transition compared to different html for different pages. When I used different html, it showed white screen for a fraction of second on page transition. And after switching to this approach, that issue is solved and also, performance is far better now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response.
can you provide me with some opensource templates/examples/samples please.

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/10-jquery-mobile-demo-websites/) and [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/) @AbhishankMaurya